# Highcharts and Json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have been trying to learn to use Highctarts.js recently and have ran into a small issue.

When I use their example code, and their example data.json file it works. However when I replace their json file with my own it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

**Highchart JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

**Highchart data.json**

```
[
[1,12],
[2,5],
[3,18],
[4,13],
[5,7],
[6,4],
[7,9],
[8,10],
[9,15],
[10,22]
]
```

This successfully produces a graph on page load.

My code doesn't, any ideas what's wrong?

**My JS** (exacy same as Highchart.js above only replaced the json file)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('results.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

**My results.json**

```
[
  {
    "Month": "January",
    "Count": 162690
  },
  {
    "Month": "February",
    "Count": 109986
  },
  {
    "Month": "March",
    "Count": 145303
  },
  {
    "Month": "April",
    "Count": 116949
  },
  {
    "Month": "May",
    "Count": 253523
  },
  {
    "Month": "June",
    "Count": 51920
  }
]
```

The **monthConn.php** page code I use to generate the json is as follows - perhaps I'm not creating the results.json correctly?;

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT 
                            MONTHNAME(TimeStamp), direction, COUNT(*)
                        FROM
                            transactions
                                WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
                        GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP);");

$stmt -> execute();

$stmt -> bind_result($month, $count);

while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
$data[] = array(
            'Month' => $month,
            'Count' => $count
      );
    }

$stmt->close();

file_put_contents("results.json", json_encode(($data)));
```

Ideally I would like a bar chart

- months along the bottom (x axis)
- count alont left (y axis)

Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/)

Comment: This is because HC wait for an array of arrays and you are sending an array of objects. If you returns the json with php, use json_decode($json, true);

Comment: Array data is treated as a set of coordinate pairs [x, y] and that's why it works without any additional chart configuration. If you want to use another data format, you should configure chart accordingly. In other words, your data is ok, your chart config is not.

Comment: This is a guess, from what I see from your post. Perhaps the @IgorDymov 's answer is more correct than mine

Comment: @johnny_s since HighCharts is extremely flexible tool, I have no idea what goal you are trying to achieve. How your chart should look like?

Comment: @johnny_s, and currently you have only Out data, right? (`Direction: O`)

Comment: @johnny_s, please add `I` data to the sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had another look at this and realised the Highchart options were incorrectly formatted.

I've created a working example here. http://jsfiddle.net/z9mgt4r6/

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://mockbin.org/bin/bd057e57-36e7-4d24-a238-32d19fc23d2c', function (data) {
        var options = {
            title: {text: 'Title'},
            subtitle: {text: 'Subtitle'},
            xAxis: {categories: []},
            yAxis: {title: {text: 'Count'}},
            series: [{name: 'Count', data: []}]
        };
        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            options.xAxis.categories.push(data[i].Month);
            options.series[0].data.push(data[i].Count);
        };
        $('#container').highcharts(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did it solve your question? It's a simple for loop http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp I created a new array to place our items into, for each month in the results.json insert a new array `z[i] = [i+1, count]`

Comment: Sorry I should have provided a jsfiddle from the start, I've updated the answer with a working example

Comment: Thanks Edward but your example doesn't seem to be working. No graph showing.

Comment: Your JSON was correct, jsfiddle works best in Chrome http://i.imgur.com/N2kCxQU.png

Comment: Thanks. Why is the x axis in reverse order?

Comment: I managed to fix this by adding `reversed: true` to my xAxis options.

Comment: You'll find lots of weird things with highcharts, welcome to the party :)